# Laravel Blade Shorthand Ternary Operator not working

Tags: laravel-5.1, ternary-operator, laravel-blade

I am using laravel collective to generate my forms and in one of the dropdown I have the following ternary operator which works:

```
 {!! Form::select('department_id', ['' => 'Please select'] + $departments, isset($user->departmentStaff->department_id) ? $user->departmentStaff->department_id : null , ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

However the laravel shorthand ternary operator doesn't work, it throws an error:

```
{!! Form::select('department_id', ['' => 'Please select'] + $departments, $user->departmentStaff->department_id or null , ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

This is from the official docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#control-structures

Comment: I don't think the short-cut is meant to be used inside a method call. Besides, you really aren't gaining a lot readability by using it, which would be the only point of using it anyway. Why don't you take all that logic and put in on the controller generating the view or on the `User` or `DepartmentStaff` models instead?